# How to use the "-" constructor in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

So I need to create a Prolog predicate that takes an input that looks like this `[true-X, false-Y, false-X, true-Z]` and only return the variables that occur once. So for this example, it would return `[true-Z]` since Z only occurs once. I have been able to do this with just normal lists.

```
singles([],[]).

singles([H | T], L) :-    
     member(H, T), 
     delete(T, H, Y),
     singles( Y, L).

singles([H | T], [H|T1]) :- 
      \+member(H, T),
      singles(T, T1).
```

If I run this then it returns

```
?- singles([1,1,2,3,4,3,3,2], R).
R = [4]
```

since it only returns the values that appear once in the list. The problem with what I'm trying to do is that I can't use the `member` or `delete` predicates with the "-" constructor. Basically, I have to start by splitting each item into it's two parts and then just compare the variable `singles([Pol-Var | T], L)`. To compare the two variables, I created an `occurs` predicate that compares the variable at the head of the list.

```
occurs(X, [Pol-Var|T]) :- X == Var.
```

Here's what I have so far.

```
singles([],[]).

singles([Pol-Var | T], L) :- 
     occurs(Var, T),
     singles(T, L).

singles([Pol-Var | T], [Pol-Var|T1]) :- 
      \+occurs(Var, T),
      singles(T, T1).

occurs(X, [Pol-Var|T]) :- X == Var.
```

What this does is basically like if I had the input `[1,1,2,3,2]` then the output would be `[1,2,3,2]` so it just removes any duplicates that are right beside eachother. So if I had the input `[true-X, false-X, false-Y, true-Y, true-Z]` then the output would be `[false-X, true-Y, true-Z]` and I want it to be `[true-Z]`. How can I do that?

Comment: Your original code is closer to working than you think, the "problem" is that it unifies free variables. I quote "problem" because unwanted unification usually is more of a symptom of a bad data structure than missing code. This really has nothing to do with using `-` as a constructor and everything to do with the fact that you want a custom kind of equality along with custom handling of Prolog variables and it's getting in the way of the simple solutions.

Comment: I'm new to prolog so I'm not sure how this stuff works. What do you mean when you say custom equality and handling of prolog variables? Would my `occurs` predicate be a custom kind of equality? The thing is my second code almost works exactly like my first code if I use the `delete` predicate. The problem is that I can't use that predicate with the `-` constructor.

Comment: Look what happens when you run `singles([true-X, false-X, false-Y, true-Y, true-Z], S)` versus `singles([true-x, false-x, false-y, true-y, true-z], S).` with your original implementation.

Comment: I understand the problem with the first one and as far I know, the second predicate fixes the unwanted unification but it no longer does what I want it to do.

Comment: I think if I knew _why_ you needed this, I might be able to help you figure out a better representation for your data. Then your first version would most likely be sufficient and you wouldn't have to wage war against Prolog's fundamentals as you're trying to do in your second version and not enjoying.

Comment: The input is a list of clauses. Each clause has a variable and it's polarity (which is either true or false). What I want the output to be is the pure literals which are the variables that only appear once in the list. So for example, the list `[true-X, false-X, true-Y, false-Y, true-Z]` should return `[true-Z]` since Z only appears once in the list and only has one polarity. The first predicate works for any list that doesn't have a variable but once I start adding in variables, we get that unwanted unification.

Comment: I understand what you want. I don't understand why you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out in his first comment, the real problem you're facing is the unwanted unification performed by Prolog between the arguments of such builtins like member/2 or delete/3. An old `trick-of-the-trade` of the Prolog community is to use *double negation* to achieve matching *without* unification, but as we'll see, this would not help you too much.

The simpler way to solve your problem, seems to rewrite member/2 and delete/3, so a possibility could be:

```
singles([],[]).

singles([H | T], L) :-
     member_(H, T),
     delete_(T, H, Y),
     singles(Y, L).

singles([H | T], [H | T1]) :-
      \+member_(H, T),
      singles(T, T1).

member_(_-H, [_-T|_]) :- H == T, !.
member_(E, [_|R]) :- member_(E, R).

delete_([], _, []).
delete_([_-T|Ts], F-H, Rs) :- T == H, !, delete_(Ts, F-H, Rs).
delete_([T|Ts], H, [T|Rs]) :- delete_(Ts, H, Rs).
```

that yields

```
?- singles([true-X, false-Y, false-X, true-Z],S).
S = [false-Y, true-Z]
```

You can see you underspecified your requirements: from your test case, seems we should delete every occurrence of `false-VAR` irrespectively of VAR...